Can I modify the Spring Framework version set by the Apache NiFi official settings?
The default Spring Framework version used by Apache NiFi-1.25.0 is 5.3.31, but a security scan identified the 'CVE 2024-22243' vulnerability. According to https://spring.io/security/cve-2024-22243, this vulnerability requires an upgrade to Spring Framework 5.3.32. How should I address this issue?
I attempted to replace all related spring*.jar files in NiFi, but after the replacement, NiFi fails to start.
I replaced the following files:
cp /home/ubuntu/spring_jar/spring-core-5.3.33.jar /home/servers/nifi-1.25.0/lib/properties/
cp /home/ubuntu/spring_jar/spring-aop-5.3.33.jar /home/servers/nifi-1.25.0/lib/properties/
cp /home/ubuntu/spring_jar/spring-context-5.3.33.jar /home/servers/nifi-1.25.0/lib/properties/
cp /home/ubuntu/spring_jar/spring-jcl-5.3.33.jar /home/servers/nifi-1.25.0/lib/properties/
cp /home/ubuntu/spring_jar/spring-beans-5.3.33 .jar /home/servers/nifi-1.25.0/lib/properties/
cp /home/ubuntu/spring_jar/spring-expression-5 .3.33.jar /home/servers/nifi-1.25.0/lib/properties/
cp /home/ubuntu/spring_jar/spring-web-5.3.33.jar /home/servers/nifi-1.25.0/lib/properties/

I also downloaded these NAR packages, replaced the 'spring-*.jar' files inside them, and re-uploaded them to the source directory.
nifi-1.19.1/lib
nif-1.25.0/lib/
nifi-framework-nar-1.25.0.nar
nfi-email-nar-1.25.0.nar
nifi-hashicorp-vault-nar-1.25.0.nar
nifi-hwx-schema-registry-nar-1.25.0.nar
nifi-jms-processors-nar-1.25.0.nar
nifi-kerberos-iaa-providers-nar-1 .25.0.nar
nifi-ldap-iaa-providers-nar-1.25.0.nar
nifi-redis-nar-1 .25.0.nar
nifi-redis-service-api-nar-1.25.0.nar
nifi-spring-nar-1.25.0.nar


There is no Spring 3.5.31, so not sure which version is being used.

Sorry, I made a typo, it was 5.3.31
